# How to enumerate active windows on the desktop Win7 with Visual FoxPro

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-foxpro

I need to enumerate the desktop windows to get a handle of an application like Internet Explorer.  I have figured out a way to do it by sending keys to Desktop to emulate ALT+TAB which invokes the Task Switching mechanism. I activate each window so I can get the Handle and Caption.  I then use the caption to figure out if that is the window of interest.  But that is an ugly solution.

I am aware of the "`EnumThreadWindows function`" which works with "`EnumThreadWndProc callback function`"  But i do not know how to implement it in VFP.  In particular, I do not know how to imply the DeskTop in the function call.

```
BOOL WINAPI EnumThreadWindows(
  _In_  DWORD dwThreadId,
  _In_  WNDENUMPROC lpfn,
  _In_  LPARAM lParam
);
```

The first parameter  "`dwThreadId`" implies the ID of the Thread and all I can think of is that the windows are children of the DeskTop.  So how do I specify that?

If anyone has some experience with Window Functions, if you know how to help me here, I would be appreciative

DK

Comment: You seem to be doing things the hard way. [`EnumWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) enumerates all top-level windows (the technical term for "desktop windows"); why not use that? What do you want to do with the desired window?

Comment: I am trying to do some automation to speed up some tasks.  I am aware of OLE Automation and use it quite a lot.  But some things simply cannot be done with OLE.

Comment: @andlabs  I might well be doing it wrong.  I am trying to find a specific window so I can click on it and send some data to it.  I figured that enumerating them I can stumble into the one I want by testing the caption

Comment: You should still be able to enumerate the top-level windows with just `EnumWindows()` and [`GetWindowText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetWindowTextLength()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); no need to fool around with threads.

Comment: I will play with EnumWindows function...  thanks for the suggestion.  I never even saw that function.  That's why I was looking at the Threaded version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the "Listing child windows for the Windows desktop" VFP sample code at news2news.com do what you want?:

http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?example=27&PHPSESSID=0544069194f7f507abc54ddebcbe26a0

Comment: Provide context for links. Link-only answers are not good answers. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: DeKoss, you're welcome! @IInspectable : you are right, and I usually would do so - in this case not, since the linked article contains only the quoted title and the sample code, where the latter is explicitly private property of the site owner, as far as i know